# Задача по пицце подскажите в каком направлении двигаться?

Tags: python, dict

В базе данных интернет-магазина PizzaTime хранятся данные о том, кто, что и сколько заказывал у них в определённый период. Вам нужно структурировать эту информацию, а также понять, сколько всего пицц купил каждый заказчик.

На вход в программу подаётся N заказов. Каждый заказ представляет собой строку вида «Покупатель — название пиццы — количество заказанных пицц». Реализуйте код, который выводит список покупателей и их заказов по алфавиту. Учитывайте, что один человек может заказать одно и то же несколько раз.

Answer (score 0):

Смотри, я думаю что ты новичок, поэтому распишу всё подробно в шагах:

1. Считай число `N`, чтобы мы могли пройтись по коду столько раз, сколько у нас покупателей
2. Считай сам ввод. Так как он у тебя в формате "покупатель - пицца - количество", то тут всё довольно просто - подсказка, используй метод [`split()`](https://pythonru.com/baza-znanij/razdelit-stroku-split?ysclid=lfrchg53bn542262914) и передай в него подстроку, по которой нужно разделить главную строку
3. Создай вне цикла словарь, назовём его `database`, в нём будут хранится данные о пользователях и их заказах
4. С каждой новой итерацией цикла, мы будем *считывать ввод и проверять, есть ли уже такой покупатель в нашей базе*. В случае если он **есть**, то мы далее проверяем, *заказывал ли он уже такую пиццу*. Здесь могут возникнуть сложности с хранением данных. Можно их хранить как строки `"<пицца>: <количество>"`, но для новичка таким способом будет сложно понять общее количество заказанных пицц, если он опять закажет такую же пиццу, поэтому для начала можно просто добавить строку названия пиццы `<количество>` раз. Т.е:

Если пользователь введёт
`Andrew - pepperoni - 3`

То список базы данных мы пополним на:
`["pepperoni", "pepperoni", "pepperoni"]`

Потом на стадии вывода мы можем просто посчитать итоговое количество строк `"pepperoni"` в списке, это и будет являтся нашим кол-вом заказанных пицц.

5. Для извлечения данных из словаря можно использовать метод [`items()`](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-slovarjami-dict-python/metod-dict-items/), который возвращает список пар-кортежей, состоящих из ключа и значения. В нашем случае ключ - имя покупателя и значение - список строк заказанных пицц. Сортировать их можно с помощью [`sorted()`](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/vozmozhnosti-i-primery-funkcii-sorted-v-python?ysclid=lfrcj3pg7a762350723), передав в параметр `key` функцию для сортировки.

Если вывод всё таки нужен типа "<пицца> : <количество>", то ты можешь воспользоваться [**этой**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-do-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item) статьей.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!